# OGR/Python evaluate "ogr_style"

Tags: qgis, python, ogr

I would like to evaluate an ogr_style string into the individual fields.
No problem as long as the separator (comma) does not appear in the textpart.
Example:

```
LABEL(f:"Arial",t:"%%c 0,40m",a:11,s:0.5g,c:#000000)
```

Is there a simple way to resolve the string with python?

Comment: This appears to be a pure Python question